# Разбить строку регулярным выражением

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

При составлении регулярного выражения не получается сохранить каждую часть входного пути. Входная строка:

```
path = "L:/Dir/Directory/";
regex e("^([A-Z]):/(([A-Za-z]+)/)*$");
if (regex_search(path, m, e, fl))...
```

При данном регулярном выражении в массив m сохраняется первая большая буква ("L") и последняя часть пути "Directory". Нужно, чтобы сохранялись все части входного пути (в том числе и "Dir").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего в данном случае разбить строку на части с помощью `:?/` (`:?` находит 1 или 0 знаков `:`, а `/` находит 1 `/`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex rx(":?/");
    string path = "L:/Dir/Directory/";
    vector<string> names(sregex_token_iterator(path.begin(), path.end(), rx, -1),
                               sregex_token_iterator());

    for( auto & p : names ) cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Результат работы программы](https://ideone.com/sXebC8):

```
L
Dir
Directory
```